# How to find ten lowest values in a column without using heapq.nsmallest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

[datafrme (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgE6B.png) I am trying to find the ten lowest values on a column of my dataframe and find the min, max and std of them. When I use heapq.nsmallest(10, a).describe, I,m getting an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute. Is there any other way I can work out my way?

```
#mean, max, min, std, medium of the ten lowest values of latitude values    
  import heapq
  lat = data['latd']
  heapq.nsmallest(10, lat).describe()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-4d7caab1e14f> in <module>()
      2 import heapq
      3 lat = data['latd']
----> 4 heapq.nsmallest(10, lat).describe()

 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'describe'
```

Comment: Could you provide the code, and small input - expected output pair?

Comment: If you already have a dataframe, then you shouldn't need heapq at all. You can either `sort_values` on the column, or just use the built-in [pandas nsmallest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in pandas methods:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[70,69,58,47,36,25,14,53,38,58],'b':[13,24,35,46,57,86,79,80,39,17]})

    a   b
0   70  13
1   69  24
2   58  35
3   47  46
4   36  57
5   25  86
6   14  79
7   53  80
8   38  39
9   58  17

df.nsmallest(5,'a')

    a   b
6   14  79
5   25  86
4   36  57
8   38  39
3   47  46

df.nsmallest(5,'a').describe()


a   b
count   5.000000    5.000000
mean    32.000000   61.400000
std 12.747549   20.452384
min 14.000000   39.000000
25% 25.000000   46.000000
50% 36.000000   57.000000
75% 38.000000   79.000000
max 47.000000   86.000000
```

For a single column, just pass in just a single column and call it on the resulting series

```
df['a'].nsmallest(5).describe()
```

Comment: How do you find values of one column only?

Comment: Pass in just a single column and call it on the series `df['a'].nsmallest(5).describe()`

Comment: Glad it worked, I'll edit the last comment into the original answer for completeness. Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: missing the numpy variants … np.sort(a)[-5:]  or  a[np.argsort(a)][:5]

Comment: This is true, however if it's already in a DataFrame and OP is also trying to get the stats, it makes sense to use the built-in methods